# How to reference Bokeh quad values on-hover within callback

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to extract column-data-source values from a bokeh quad when I hover over it.

Right now I can only find two variables in the callback scope.
`cb_obj`  and `cb_data`

```
code = """
    console.log(cb_obj);
    console.log(cb_data)
""" 

callback = CustomJS(code=code)

quad_plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback))
```

Being relatively new to Javascript, I'm having trouble traversing and understanding the `cb_obj` and `cb_data` output in my inspector/in-browser console.

I was wondering how I might reference the values of a quad I'm currently hovering over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cb_data contains the indices relating to the currently hovered glyph. You can then use that to index the underlying data for what ever purposes you want.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CustomJS, ColumnDataSource

top = [2, 3, 4]
bottom = [1, 2, 3]
left = [1, 2, 3]
right = [1.2, 2.5, 3.7]
data = {'top':top, 'bottom':bottom, 'left':left, 'right':right}
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
quad_plot = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
quad_plot.quad(top="top", bottom="bottom", left="left",
    right="right",source=source, color="#B3DE69")

code = """
    var hovered_ind = cb_data.index['1d'].indices[0];
    var data = source.data
    console.log(hovered_ind)
    if(hovered_ind != undefined){
        console.log('inside', hovered_ind)
        var top = data['top'][hovered_ind]
        var bottom = data['bottom'][hovered_ind]
        var left = data['left'][hovered_ind]
        var right = data['right'][hovered_ind]
        console.log(top, bottom, left, right)
    }
""" 


callback = CustomJS(code=code, args={'source': source})

quad_plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback))  

show(quad_plot)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What would I be referencing if I were to use '2d' or '3d'?